# How to reassign task into Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, task, variable-assignment

As in Hadoop, If a task fails, it assign to another node, How to reassign task to another?
I'm wanna into MapReduce program when a task was assigned to a specific node (My desired node e.g. node 1), this task will be reassigned (e.g. to node 2). How to do this work? Do have an idea?

(I'm using Hadoop 2.9.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign a task to another node or set of nodes if you are using Node Labels.  Hadoop is designed to run on many nodes (like 20 to 500 nodes for most users) so your use case is not one which will be covered by normal operations.  If you really want to pursue this you have 2 options:

- Use Capacity Scheduling and Node Labels
- Write a custom Application Master so you can control which Node Managers you want to launch containers to.

#### References

- [YARN Node Labels](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html)
- [Hadoop: Writing YARN Applications: Writing an ApplicationMaster (AM)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html#Writing_an_ApplicationMaster_AM)